# Wordpress missing thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have a problem with wordpress theme, thumbnails missing images after refresh sometimes ok

[My website](http://womensupply.com/category/dress/)

[Problem image](http://www.part.lt/img/48f85755577a0f5625d2e7219d740c4b246.png)

Answer (score 0):

most likely related to timthumb.

your theme uses thumb.php

read this - http://www.der-prinz.com/images-displaying-solving-issues-timthumb/ 
it may help

also be aware of timthumb http://markmaunder.com/2011/08/01/zero-day-vulnerability-in-many-wordpress-themes/ see the executive summary section.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are refreshing browser using ctrl + f5 (windows only)
possibly images are coming from cache.
Secondly timthumb sometimes required relative paths to load images properly.
I faced this issue number of times with error 403 forbidden.
hope it helps.